# Get the JS to trigger in just one of ten equal divs that displays in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**This is what I have until now:** An avatar image that functions as the class "*oros*". On top of it, I have another class, named "*josito*". josito contains the profile information, and it's hided so that when you hover on top of the avatar, it will display itself.

**The issue:** At the same time, I wanted the avatar imaged to get blurred. I kinda achieved it with JS. So when I hover on josito, oros gets blurred. And I say "kinda" because the html markup it repeats itself automatically ten times in the same page. So when I hover one avatar, the other nine get blurry to. *I just want to blur the one I'm hovering on.*

Here the JS I have until now:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".josito2").mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(".oros").addClass("blur");
        });
});
```

And I added this one to, so when I take away the mouse, it will turn back normal:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".josito2").mouseleave(function(){
    jQuery(".oros").removeClass("blur");
        });
});
```

HTML markup:

```
<td>
                                      <div class="oros">{postrow.displayed.POSTER_AVATAR}</div>
                                        </td><td class="oros12">
                    <div class="josito"><div class="josito2"><div id="josito3">

                                        <div class="oros2"><div class="plate">{postrow.displayed.POSTER_NAME}</div>
                                              <div class="oros3">{postrow.displayed.POSTER_RANK_NEW}</div></div>
                </div></div></div>

                                        </td>
```

(It is just a part ot the entire thing)
Please note:
 1. English it is not my native tongue, so if you need further explanation, please tell me : )
 2. I got the code from other answers here, so a lot of thanks to those who wrote it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [event target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
jQuery("josito2").mouseover(function(e){
  jQuery(e.target).addClass("blur");
});

jQuery(".josito2").mouseleave(function(e){
  jQuery(e.target).removeClass("blur");
});
```

Comment: Vik, it seems that didn't work. The effect doesn't get triggered either. I updated the codes on my post, making a few arrangements. The one that's placed now is the one I was actually using, I got confused, sorry. Though I don't think it chaged that much. Would it be helpful if I chaged the classes for ID's?